# How to sort an HTML table with multiple columns in javascript and/or jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, arrays, jquery-ui-sortable

So I like to learn on my own and get help. I do not want to use a javascript/jquery plugin because I want to develop my own code. So how would I sort a table by alphabetical order on a click of a button? When they click the button, The row will alphabetize and the rest of the row will follow suit, according to the column that is being sorted. Thanks!

```
<table id=sortableTable">
    <thead id="myTHead">
      <tr>
         <th> Month </th>
         <th> Population </th>
      </tr>
   </thead>
   <tbody id="myBody">
<tr>
<td>March</td>
<td>100</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>April</td>
<td>300</td>
</tr>
 <tr>
<td>Febuary</td>
<td>200</td>
</tr>
```

Comment: OK, if you want to develop your own code, what have you tried so far?

Comment: I have tried just doing an unordered list. I got that to sort. Then I tried putting the same thought process and format into a table and it does not work, even worse i would have to sort it by the column and the rows follow it

Answer (score 0):

I am not going to give you a code example, because what you are asking would be a fairly long bit of code.  But what you would need to do approach wise is to make sure you had all you tables elements generated with a specific ID. Probably something of the format id="colnum_rownum".

If you had a sort button for each column, they would likely need their own ID;s as well like id="sort_colnum".

When you clicked that button you would want to call a function that would get all the elements containing the ID of the column you clicked.  You would then sort them to understand what row numbers needed to be moved where.  You would then move those rows within the DOM to their new locations, and probably modify the id's to reflect their new locations so that you could sort again later when another button is clicked.

While it is an interesting thing to work through such a thing from an academic understanding standpoint. From a practical standpoint, it would be crazy to spend time implementing such a thing when there are a number of good solutions for this already.

Comment: If by a plug-in you mean that you will not be loading ANY external javascript frameworks or third-party scripts, then no, you are pretty much left to building it yourself.

Answer (score 0):

I have just found this in another post with a similar topic:

http://www.allmyscripts.com/Table_Sort/

By the read of it is an open source sorting function in javasript for html tables.
Seems interesting, simple and useful.